# How do I pass variables into an html template and use them as img source

Tags: html, image, go, templates

I am working on a web server.
My goal is to load an image using a base64 string and display that image on the site.
The base64 string should vary depending what variable I use to load the template.

This is my Go rendering code:

```
varmap := map[string]interface{}{
    "username": discordTag,
    "b64":      "data:image/png;base64,looongstring",
}
fmt.Println("logged in!")
templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", varmap)
```

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome back, {{ .username }} {{ .b64 }}</h1>
      <img src="{{ .b64 }}"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The displaying of the username works fine and displaying the base64 string as text works fine aswell.
[Displaying of Username works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzW5w.png)

[Looking at the HTML the browser renders, the img src shows up as "#ZgotmplZ"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywRwP.png)

Comment: You need to put your `src` attribute value in quotes, and remove the spaces around the `=`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, still the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [html/template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package which escapes strings to prevent code injection. You can wrap your base64 dataurl in `template.URL` to tell the template engine that how to treat your string.

```golang
varmap := map[string]interface{}{
    "username": discordTag,
    "b64":      template.URL("data:image/png;base64,looongstring"),
}
```

I should note that unless the images are very small it might be better to serve them statically rather than embedding the into the html.